# Difference between HTML display and React render of same raw HTML

Tags: reactjs

I have a raw HTML that I want to render in a React component. When I open the HTML file, the display is correct but when the same HTML is rendered by React using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, the display changes.
Here is an example:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

txt = '<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body><div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:412px; top:221px; width:106px; height:81px;"><span style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size:8px">Name <br>Forename <br>01.01.1901 <br>female <br>12345 <br>DD.MM.YYYY  <br>DD.MM.YYYY <br>8765432 <br>DD.MM.YYYY <br></span></div><span style="position:absolute; border: gray 1px solid; left:0px; top:50px; width:595px; height:841px;"></span><div style="position:absolute; top:50px;"><a name="1">Page 1</a></div><span style="position:absolute; border: black 1px solid; left:328px; top:214px; width:207px; height:94px;"></span></body></html>'

root.render(<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: txt}} />);
```

With React:
[image: Using React]

When open the .html file containing the same code as in the txt variable:

[image]

Why this difference between the two displays and how can I make React display the HTML properly?

EDIT: Like it was mentioned in the comments, by adding 'display: block' to the span it will make the display correct, but the question is: **How can I do that without modifying the HTLM, only from React?** Because the example I gave is part of a much larger .html file with lots of spans and not all of them need 'display: block'.

Comment: If `root` is a `div` then you're putting `<html>` as a child. `<html>` should be the root element. Try rendering the inner HTML of your `<body>` without `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`.

Comment: root it's just: const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); I was creating the example using this hello world : https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/MjrdWg?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

delete the html and head and body tag

just put there the div that contain the content

probably it works fine

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it does not work.

Comment: can you create a codesandbox link?

Comment: If you will do ‘display: block’ for span it will be same as html version.

Comment: Thank, indeed ‘display: block’ for span makes it the same, but is there a way to make the display the same without modifying the html? Something so the react treats the span as a 'display: block'?

Comment: react doesnt do that. react only prepare js to create html and css. browser will render them.